# CakePHP email sending with photo

Tags: email, cakephp

I have a cakePhp project and i wants to send email with photo using cakephp email. Sending email is fine , but photo is not printed inside the body.I am giving full url of image. Code sample are below:

I could not find out the proper way to send image with email.

```
<td style="text-align: right;">
  <img alt="" width="120" height="120" src="http://localhost/lictors/app/webroot/img/lict/passport_copy.jpg"> 

</td>
```

Comment: if i give my ip address , is it will work?

Comment: I read it..but its not working...

Comment: You mean you can't see image on your email? This image url has `localhost` in it, meaning it can't be seen from public. You need to find some url that is not on your `localhost`, use some image from google search and try that.

Comment: Thank u...i got my solution...

Comment: @invention, did you find something to display Localhost Images in the Email?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to attach the image like this:

```
$email->attachments([
    'photo.png' => [
        'file' => '/full/some_hash.png',
        'mimetype' => 'image/png',
        'contentId' => 'my-unique-id'
    ]
]);
```

After that you refer the contentId int the img src, like this:

```
<img src="cid:my-unique-id">
```